# ARC Welder - prevent applications from freezing / hibernating

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm using new Google Chrome ARC Welder app to convert Android apks to Chrome applications. The problem I'm facing is that these apps freeze if they aren't used for some time.

While I understand that this is the desired bahaviour to save power on laptops and CPU time on desktops I have an application that needs to run even though I'm not clicking anything on the screen.

Can I set/run Android apps on Chrome and prevent them from sleeping/hibernating?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the equivalent in Android of the device going to sleep.

If you hold a wake lock the app will not go to sleep, just like Android.  This is the preferred way to signal to the runtime that you want to keep it active.

A more blunt way to do it is with special ARC metadata:

`{"sleepOnBlur": false}`

This will prevent your whole app from going to sleep all the time, at the expense of battery/cpu.